# How is memory handled by the 'new/delete' constructors and destructors in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

After some time in C-world, I reviewing C++. I have a basic question that I will frame around the implementation of a list-based stack.

The class 'ListStack' has a 'Node' struct type. This is the relevant part of the header file ListStack.h:

```
private:
    int count;
    struct Node{
        Node *next;
        void *data;
    }
    Node *head;
```

And in ListStack.cpp here are the constructor and destructor. In the destructor I am freeing the data which the client has dynamically allocated themselves (pretend that this is the case, ignore the design) but not freeing any nodes:

```
ListStack::ListStack(){
    head = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

ListStack::~ListStack(){
    while (head != NULL){
        void *data = pop();
        free (data);
    }
}
```

Is this a correct approach? The hazy areas for me are:

1) Each new node created via `Node *new = new Node` which makes me think that I have to free the nodes by calling delete. However, as you can see the struct Node (defined in header) doesn't have a destructor, so what would delete do?

2) I feel that the freeing process is incorrect, should I be calling delete data? How would you even free data that the client dynamically allocated if you don't know whether they used malloc or new?

Coming from C, whether everything about memory was very clear, it's hazy to me when data has to be handled (free'd or deleted) manually and when C++ takes care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

> However, as you can see the struct Node (defined in header) doesn't
>   have a destructor, so what would delete do?

Delete will free the memory that you have allocated. Also, the compiler will create a default destructor for `Node` since you have not declared one. This default destructor will be called when you call delete. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor (*Implicitly-declared destructor* and *Implicitly-defined destructor*):

*If no user-defined destructor is provided for a class type (`struct`, `class`, or `union`), the compiler will always declare a destructor as an inline public member of its class.*

2)

> should I be calling delete data?

You need to delete / free all memory that the instance owns. In your case I guess that you need to iterate over the list and delete each node. Make sure to keep a pointer to the next node before you delete the current node, or else it will be lost. So something like this:

```
ListStack::~ListStack()
{
    Node* currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

This will only delete the `Node`s. If you allocated the `data` field dynamically as well you will need a `delete currentNode->data` there too.

> How would you even free data that the client dynamically allocated if
>   you don't know whether they used malloc or new?

I'm not sure what you mean here. Since you are writing the class you'll know whether you used malloc or new to allocate the memory, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: You're writing C++.  Unless you're pulling in old C code, all of your new code should be using `new` and not `malloc`.

Comment: And if you're writing modern C++ (C++11/14/17) you should be using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`) and never have to use `new` and `delete`, just `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`.